# Node.js : using child_process to send images to clients?

Tags: node.js

What is the best way to serve many files (images) to many clients, in order to be able to serve them at the same time ?

For example, a server has to serve each second :
- 3,000 small images (1 ko each)
- 750 big images (100 ko each)
There are 150 clients.

I wonder that using child_process would help ?
I am looking for a solution (to build) using only node.js and without library.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the native [http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module to service the HTTP side of this and the async parts of the native [fs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module to read the files.  Don't go beyond the simple approach until you find that isn't sufficient.

I expect it will work just fine as this is exactly the sort of thing node.js is designed to be good at.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to have alook at the [sendfile(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) syscall. Is node.js really a requirement? If not I would like to suggest just using Nginx or Apache HTTPD as they are really stable, well established and performant (especially fo static files).